# Show $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^n \frac{dx}{x^n + x^2 + 1} = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, rational-functions

Show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^n \frac{dx}{x^n + x^2 + 1} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Use dominated convergence theorem. All these functions are dominated by $1/(x^2+1)$

Comment: Who downvoted ?

Comment: are you serious? after all the time you spend on this site, you pose such a question? Easy closevote....

Comment: @Crostul ? Convergeance test to show the value of the limit ??

Comment: Yes you are right !

Comment: @tired my apologies.this is trivial.

Comment: @tired, If the OP had less reputation it would've been closed by now.

Comment: Yes but on the other hand, it is a Nice example of dominated convergeance. Though simple.

Comment: The problem isn't that the question is simple but you post a question that is missing context and showing no effort at all.

Comment: Hey , i can not be smart all the time :p

Comment: @Zaid : Well this might not be my best question. You can complain about Upvotes for my bad questions , but not all (my) good questions get upvotes ... So its statistical justice :p. As for the effort, it seems impossible without dominated convergeance. And as for context : I disagree that context is needed all the time , in particular for calculus. Curiosity and willing to learn is imho sufficient. And forgive me, I did not do calculus for a while ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write, for $n>1$,
$$
\begin{align}
0\le\int_0^n \frac{dx}{x^n + x^2 + 1} &=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^n + x^2 + 1} +\int_1^n \frac{dx}{x^n + x^2 + 1}
\end{align}
$$ we have
$$
0\le\int_1^n \frac{dx}{x^n + x^2 + 1} \le\int_1^n \frac{dx}{x^n} \le\frac1{n-1}
$$ and, by the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), one has
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^n + x^2 + 1} =\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2 + 1} \:dx=\frac \pi4.
$$

Comment: the last line/equation does not require the $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ second time. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just to mention that one can do without dominated convergence (in case one does not know about it).

First, divide the integral
$$
\int_0^n\frac{1}{x^n+x^2+1}\,dx=
\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^n+x^2+1}\,dx+
\int_1^n\frac{1}{x^n+x^2+1}\,dx
$$
and estimate the second one, just as Olivier did.

For the integral between $0$ and $1$, we just add and subtract with what we want,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^n+x^2+1}\,dx &=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,dx
+\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^n+x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,dx\\
&=\frac\pi4-\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{(x^n+x^2+1)(x^2+1)}\,dx
\end{aligned}
$$
Since, on $[0,1]$,
$$
\Bigl|\frac{x^n}{(x^n+x^2+1)(x^2+1)}\Bigr|\leq x^n
$$
we find by the triangle inequality that
$$
\biggl|\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{(x^n+x^2+1)(x^2+1)}\,dx\biggr|\leq\int_0^1 x^n\,dx=\frac{1}{n+1}.
$$
The statement in your question follows by putting the pieces together.

Comment: This is the elementary way, thanks. (+1)

Comment: @mickep Nice. At Olivier your gratitude is inspirational. At both +1. Mickep your a mick too !! Lol